# Permissions issue with Docker and Mac OSX

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am running MacOSX 10.11 and I recently tried to dockerize all my projects.

I have an issue trying to run a mongoDB + NodeJS application using docker-compose.

Here is my docker-compose script :

```
version: '2'
services:
  mongodata:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - "${APP_DB}:/data"
    command: "--break-mongo"
  mongo-app:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes_from:
      - "mongodata"
    expose:
      - "27017"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: "--smallfiles --dbpath /data"
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo-app
    links:
      - mongo-app
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
```

So basically I have a volume-only container which will persist my files. Then I run mongo based on that volume then I run my NodeJS app.

But everytime I try tto run docker-compose up, I have the following error :

```
mongo-app_1  | 2016-04-22T07:14:05.931+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data 64-bit host=4c43c9e20014
mongo-app_1  | 2016-04-22T07:14:05.931+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.5
mongodata_1     | try 'mongod --help' for more information
mongo-app_1  | 2016-04-22T07:14:05.932+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 34e65e5383f7ea1726332cb175b73077ec4a1b02
mongo-app_1  | 2016-04-22T07:14:05.932+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
mongo-app_1  | 2016-04-22T07:14:05.932+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
mongo-app_1  | 2016-04-22T07:14:05.932+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
mongo-app_1  | 2016-04-22T07:14:05.933+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
mongo-app_1  | 2016-04-22T07:14:05.933+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian71
mongo-app_1  | 2016-04-22T07:14:05.933+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
mongo-app_1  | 2016-04-22T07:14:05.933+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
mongo-app_1  | 2016-04-22T07:14:05.934+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/data", mmapv1: { smallFiles: true } } }
mongo-app_1  | 2016-04-22T07:14:05.947+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data created by the 'mmapv1' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'mmapv1'.
mongo-app_1  | 2016-04-22T07:14:05.958+0000 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/mongod.lock is not empty.
mongo-app_1  | 2016-04-22T07:14:05.959+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
mongo-app_1  | 2016-04-22T07:14:05.964+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

As far as I know it's happening on MacOSX only, I tried to CHOWN + CHMOD the /data folder but I saw a thread that says that you can't CHOWN in a container once the volume has been mounted and I can confirm that it does nothing. But since I am using a docker-compose file, I can't do that BEFORE mounting the volume.
Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Using docker-machine on MacOS you can bind volumes only inside home host directory. Other directories don't work because they are not in folder that shared by VBox. You can share your folder outside user home using `VBoxManage` :
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-sharedfolder

More info about this issue:

https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1826

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually need to mount the data directory from your host system? Can't you just use container volumes for the data folder?

The information will still be persisted on the container.

Example:

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  mongo_data: {}
services:
  mongo-app:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db
    expose:
      - "27017"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: "--smallfiles --dbpath /data/db"
```

Sources:

- https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/
- https://iainhunter.wordpress.com/2016/01/12/avoiding-pitfalls-running-mongo-3-2-in-docker-on-osx/

Comment: I have an important backup on my host that s why I am trying to do that but if I find a reliable way to import it you are right...

Comment: Have you tried mapping the volume to a different path and, after accessing to the container using docker-compose run mongo-app bash, copying the files to the desired location?
If the file is not on a host shared volume you can indeed change permissions and ownerships.

Comment: That is not working, the nodejs does not update with the new volumes_from location unless I delete the mongodata container thus removing all my permissions and ownership modifications...